# Blur Body except div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code in which I m trying to blur whole body except one `textarea` div nut could not succeed When I click on textarea whole body gets blur even using not in my script function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-control").focus(function(){
    $("body").not("div #hide").addClass("blur");
  }).blur(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("blur");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_area_home" id="hide">
  <form action="uploadFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="xAction" value="uploadFile" />
    <textarea class="form-control" name="detail" placeholder="Upload File"></textarea>
    <div class="text_area_button">
      <input  type="file" name="uploadDoc"/>
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-rect" type="submit" value="Post" />
    </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `div #hide` should be changed to `div#hide`.

Comment: nope still it dont work

Comment: What you mean by _blur whole body except one textarea_?!! add class `blur` to all body elements except textarea ?

Comment: yes @ZakariaAcharki i want to blur whole body except the form div

Comment: We don't know what `blur` means in your head so please try to describe more, and i don't think you're talking about the `blur()` function effect..

Comment: I have define `.blur` in my css where filter property is used and thus i have use addClass in the script code which makes whole body blur

Comment: Maybe there is a different way around this. What are you trying to do with this blur class?

Comment: @Loaf I have put my HTML code in the below comments section and in blur class I have used just one property of blur that is `filter: blur(2px);` thats it

Comment: @Loaf When i cut and paste my html and js just below the body tag it work how i wants but when kept in its orignal position then doesnt work

Comment: @AbhishekBurkule updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: @AbhishekBurkule The Choose File and Post button are no longer blurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drua6wg0/1/). It accomplishes it finally :)

I had to remove the class from all of the parent elements to the div class as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control").focus(function() {
    $("div").addClass("blur");
    $('#hide').parents().removeClass("blur");
    $('#hide').removeClass("blur");
    $('.text_area_button').removeClass("blur");
  }).blur(function() {
    $("div").removeClass("blur");
  });
});
```

Would like to see if anyone has a 1-liner for that add and removing classes.

Comment: still whole body gets blur

Comment: is the div a direct child of the body?

Comment: the div is in mid of the body and the script code is written just below the div

Comment: Everything gets blur even using not for that div and solution provided by you still gets the same result

Comment: I Tried using div also it doesnt work but when i used .css instead of addClass and provide their background it work for div but not for body

Comment: Take another look. :)

Comment: When I inspect this code, the things that get the blur class are the the first `<script>` tag, and that's it. Can you post more of your HTML?

Comment: the HTML code is long enough so should I post it all?